# Determining from angle if robot turn left or right

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to write soft, to project route of my robot. I have two vectors and I'm trying to determine what is their turn relative to each other (look at image). I can calculate angle, form code below, but it's not enaugh  to determine if robot suppose to turn left or right. I'm out of ideas... Any hint?

```
angle = acosf((vNewX*vOldX + vNewY*vOldY)/(NewVectorDistance*OldVectorDistance))*180.0/3.14159;
```

[image: visual image]

Comment: Check sign of `vNewX*vOldY - vNewY*vOldX`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://robotics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: how do you decide whether to turn right or left? we will need a few details.

Comment: what is vOldX and the rest of variables? do you really think we will derive it from this pic? and after we guess we give you an answer.

Comment: @P0W: It may well be on topic there, but it is certainly also on topic here.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yeah, I'm just promoting that beta site :D . I retracted my vote

Comment: I want 'minus' sign before angle if left and 'plus' if right. And the rest of code. I didn't fought, that this is necessary ^^". Sorry. 

`(its a list) vLines->Add(gcnew Microsoft::VisualBasic::PowerPacks::LineShape());`

`vNewX = vLines[numberOfLines]->X2- vLines[numberOfLines]->X1;`
`vNewY = vLines[numberOfLines]->Y2- vLines[numberOfLines]->Y1;`
`vOldX = vLines[numberOfLines-1]->X2- vLines[numberOfLines-1]->X1;`
`vOldY = vLines[numberOfLines-1]->Y2- vLines[numberOfLines-1]->Y1;`


NewLineDistance and OldLineDistance is just length of thoes vectors

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff Man! You are the best! It is working! Thx!

Comment: You want atan2 I think

Answer (score 0):

use the difference of `atan2` of one vector and `atan2` of the other vector.